# probability distribution of a random selection from one of two bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I have two bernoulli random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and that I want to randomly select from either one of them with some probability $p$.

In other words:

$X$ ~ $Be(p_X)$

$Y$ ~ $Be(p_Y)$

Then I want to know the distribution of:

$Z = pX + (1-p)Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity $Z=pX+(1−p)Y$ does not correspond to the situation you describe. Instead, one should define
$$
Z=WX+(1-W)Y,
$$ 
where $X$, $Y$ and $W$ are independent and Bernoulli with respective parameters $p_X$, $p_Y$ and $p$. Using the identities
$$[Z=1]=[W=1,X=1]\cup[W=0,Y=1],
$$
and
$$
[Z=0]=[W=1,X=0]\cup[W=0,Y=0],
$$
one sees that $Z$ is Bernoulli with parameter
$$
q=pp_X+(1-p)p_Y.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand your reasoning, but I was wondering if you could help me understand what is wrong with the reasoning in my answer? (poisson binomials also have the same expected value $q$)

Comment: Indeed, P(Z=1)=P(W=1,X=1)+P(W=0,Y=1), the events (W=1,X=1) and (W=0,Y=1) are not independent, and the proof above does not use the assumption that they are. The relevant independence properties are the independence of (W=1) and (X=1) on the one hand, and the independence of (W=0) and (Y=1) on the other hand.

Comment: ((The comment by @mobeets that my last comment answers is now deleted.))

Comment: @mobeets "I was wondering if you could help me understand what is wrong with the reasoning in my answer" Please read my comment to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I deleted the comment because I figured out what I was doing wrong. Thanks for all your clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

Let $W$ be another bernoulli random variable with the probability $p$ in the definition of $Z$.

$W$ ~ $Be(p)$

Then $Z$ can be rewritten as:

$Z$ = $WX + (1-W)Y$

Note that $1-W$ is bernoulli:

$1 - W$ ~ Be($1-p$)

And the product of two bernoulli random variables is itself a bernoulli random variable, so:

$WX$ ~ Be($p\cdot p_X$)

$(1 - W)Y$ ~ Be($(1-p)\cdot p_Y$)

The sum of independent random bernoulli variables forms a [poisson binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).

Since $WX$ and $(1-W)Y$ are independent bernoulli random variables, then $Z = WX + (1-W)Y$ is a poisson binomial random variable with parameters ($p\cdot p_X$, $(1-p)\cdot p_Y$).

Comment: The random variables (WX) and (WY) are not independent.